migrate express middleware to fastify
I have this middleware that I was making to validate the body of the login request, but it's not working at all, I needed it to say if the email and/or password is missing and return an error before sending it to the guard
import {
BadRequestException,
Injectable,
NestMiddleware,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';
import { LoginRequestBody } from '../models/LoginRequestBody';
import { validate } from 'class-validator';

@Injectable()
export class LoginValidationMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
async use(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
const body = req.body;

    const loginRequestBody = new LoginRequestBody();
    loginRequestBody.email = body.email;
    loginRequestBody.password = body.password;
    
    const validations = await validate(loginRequestBody);
    
    if (validations.length) {
      throw new BadRequestException(
        validations.reduce((acc, curr) => {
          return [...acc, ...Object.values(curr.constraints)];
        }, []),
      );
    }
    
    next();

}
}

here is my LoginRequestBody
import { IsEmail, IsString } from 'class-validator';

export class LoginRequestBody {
@IsEmail()
email: string;

@IsString()
password: string;
}

then when I tried to do it with fastify it looked like this
import { BadRequestException, Injectable, NestMiddleware } from '@nestjs/common';
import { LoginRequestBody } from '../models/LoginRequestBody';
import { FastifyRequest, FastifyReply } from 'fastify';
import { validate } from 'class-validator';

@Injectable()
export class LoginValidationMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
async use(req: FastifyRequest, res: FastifyReply, next: () =\> void) {
const body = req.body as { email: string; password: string };

      const loginRequestBody = new LoginRequestBody();
      loginRequestBody.email = body.email;
      loginRequestBody.password = body.password;
    
      const validations = await validate(loginRequestBody);
    
      if (validations.length) {
        throw new BadRequestException(
          validations.reduce((acc, curr) => {
            return [...acc, ...Object.values(curr.constraints)];
          }, []),
        );
      }
    
      next();
    }

}

but whenever I make the request, regardless of whether something is missing or not, it says the email is missing
[Nest] 297468  - 20/12/2024, 11:18:26     LOG [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmCoreModule dependencies initialized +80ms
[Nest] 297468  - 20/12/2024, 11:18:26     LOG [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 297468  - 20/12/2024, 11:18:26     LOG [InstanceLoader] UsersModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 297468  - 20/12/2024, 11:18:26     LOG [InstanceLoader] AuthModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 297468  - 20/12/2024, 11:18:26     LOG [RoutesResolver] AppController {/}: +6ms
[Nest] 297468  - 20/12/2024, 11:18:26     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/, GET} route +2ms
[Nest] 297468  - 20/12/2024, 11:18:26     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/me, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 297468  - 20/12/2024, 11:18:26     LOG [RoutesResolver] AuthController {/}: +0ms
[Nest] 297468  - 20/12/2024, 11:18:26     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/login, POST} route +1ms
[Nest] 297468  - 20/12/2024, 11:18:26     LOG [RoutesResolver] UsersController {/users}: +0ms
[Nest] 297468  - 20/12/2024, 11:18:26     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/users, POST} route +0ms
[Nest] 297468  - 20/12/2024, 11:18:26     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/users, GET} route +0ms
[Nest] 297468  - 20/12/2024, 11:18:26     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/users/:id, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 297468  - 20/12/2024, 11:18:26     LOG [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +1ms
[Nest] 297468  - 20/12/2024, 11:18:39   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'email')

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'email')
    at LoginValidationMiddleware.use (/home/vinni/Desktop/Projetos/obg-plataform/dist/services/auth-service/webpack:/src/middlewares/login-validation.middleware.ts:12:37)
    at /home/vinni/Desktop/Projetos/obg-plataform/node_modules/.pnpm/@nestjs+core@10.4.15_@nestjs+common@10.4.15_class-transformer@0.5.1_class-validator@0.14.1_re_vhlh227qw5lojdhsyzpeqdfmju/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-proxy.js:9:23
    at /home/vinni/Desktop/Projetos/obg-plataform/node_modules/.pnpm/@nestjs+platform-fastify@10.4.15_@nestjs+common@10.4.15_class-transformer@0.5.1_class-validat_k2s5nhbwpf46zqwr2irhnytkbi/node_modules/@nestjs/platform-fastify/adapters/fastify-adapter.js:334:24
    at Holder.done (/home/vinni/Desktop/Projetos/obg-plataform/node_modules/.pnpm/@fastify+middie@8.3.3/node_modules/@fastify/middie/lib/engine.js:107:13)
    at Object.run (/home/vinni/Desktop/Projetos/obg-plataform/node_modules/.pnpm/@fastify+middie@8.3.3/node_modules/@fastify/middie/lib/engine.js:59:12)
    at Object.runMiddie (/home/vinni/Desktop/Projetos/obg-plataform/node_modules/.pnpm/@fastify+middie@8.3.3/node_modules/@fastify/middie/index.js:73:21)
    at hookIterator (/home/vinni/Desktop/Projetos/obg-plataform/node_modules/.pnpm/fastify@4.28.1/node_modules/fastify/lib/hooks.js:405:10)
    at next (/home/vinni/Desktop/Projetos/obg-plataform/node_modules/.pnpm/fastify@4.28.1/node_modules/fastify/lib/hooks.js:239:18)
    at hookRunner (/home/vinni/Desktop/Projetos/obg-plataform/node_modules/.pnpm/fastify@4.28.1/node_modules/fastify/lib/hooks.js:261:5)
    at Object.routeHandler [as handler] (/home/vinni/Desktop/Projetos/obg-plataform/node_modules/.pnpm/fastify@4.28.1/node_modules/fastify/lib/route.js:527:7)

my request is like this
POST http://localhost:8002/auth/login
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "email": "teste@example.com",
    "password": "Teste123"
}

my main.ts is like this
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import {
  FastifyAdapter,
  NestFastifyApplication,
} from '@nestjs/platform-fastify';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
    AppModule,
    new FastifyAdapter()
  );

  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());

  app.enableCors();

  await app.listen(process.env.PORT ?? 8002);
}
bootstrap();

my auth.module.ts is like this
import { MiddlewareConsumer, Module, NestModule } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { AuthController } from './auth.controller';
import { UsersModule } from '../../../users-service/src/users/users.module';
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';

import { LocalStrategy } from '../strategies/local.strategy';
import { JwtStrategy } from '../strategies/jwt.strategy';
import { LoginValidationMiddleware } from '../middlewares/login-validation.middleware';


@Module({
  imports: [UsersModule, JwtModule.register({
    secret: process.env.AUTH_SERVICE_JWT_SECRET,
    signOptions: {expiresIn: '30d'}
  })],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService, LocalStrategy, JwtStrategy],
})
export class AuthModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer.apply(LoginValidationMiddleware).forRoutes('login');
  }
}

